# Targeting a styled component in React with a webpack generated identifier?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I have a component called `LargeDialog` which encapsulates a `StyledDialogContent` (both of which are from the `Dialog` class of the Material UI library).

**LargeDialog.jsx**

```
...

const StyledDialogContent = styled(DialogContent)`
  padding: 30px;
`; 


class LargeDialog extends Component {

...
  render(){
    return (<StyledDialogContent> ... </StyledDialogContent>) // Some content within.
  }

}

...
```

The styled components adds a `padding: 30px` to the `DialogContent`.

I would like to override this with `padding: 0px` if the `LargeDialog` modal is reused in another place.

However, the generated webpack CSS has a random identifier i.e. `MuiDialogContentroot-0-3-439 FullDialogModal__StyledDialogContent-ogd6um-6 iMpISc` and I'm not sure how to target this.

**AnotherComponent.jsx**

```
import LargeDialog from './LargeDialog'
...

const LargeDialogWrapper = styled(LargeDialog)`

  // What do I put here to override StyledDialogContent with a random identifier?

`;

class AnotherComponent extends Component {

}
...
```

I tried exporting `StyledDialogContent` and targetting it as such:

```
import LargeDialog, {StyledDialogContent} from './LargeDialog'

...

const LargeDialogWrapper = styled(LargeDialog)`
  ${StyledDialogContent} {
    padding: 0px;
  }
`;
```

But that didn't work too.

Example:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/styled-components-d5pzv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You target it within the style like so:

```
const Box = styled.div`
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
`;

const Yellow = styled.div`
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  ${Box} {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Box />
      <Yellow>
        <Box />
      </Yellow>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Q-58981914-StyledRefere]

Refer to the [related docs section](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components).

If it helps, you can check [this example file](https://github.com/denvash/dennisvash.com/blob/master/src/components/Timeline/Timeline.jsx) (note the `Heading` style for example).

---

> An edit after OP question update

In your example, you missing `className` if you want to enable styling for your components.

Also, you need `WrapperDiv` to be a direct child, this is how the CSS works, remember that you writing simple CSS just in javascript:

```
class LargeDialog extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WrapperDiv className={this.props.className}>
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      </WrapperDiv>
    );
  }
}

const WrapperLargeDialog = styled(LargeDialog)`
  ${WrapperDiv} {
    background-color: blue;
  }
`;
// LargeDialog should be red.
// WrapperLargeDialog should be blue.
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <LargeDialog />
        <br />
        <WrapperLargeDialog>
          <WrapperDiv />
        </WrapperLargeDialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Styled Components]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this only works if both styling are in the same Component. Attempting to do that in my case i.e. `AnotherComponent` throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: StyledDialogContent is not defined` which makes sense since the `AnotherComponent` has no visibility into `StyledDialogContent`

Comment: Ofc you need to import it

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt seem to be working for me. I checked your example and it differs slight because the styles I have are encapsulated in a `.jsx` component rather than just a styling `.js` file. I'm not sure if its the mixture for named and default exports i.e. `import LargeDialog, {StyledDialogComponent} from './LargeDialog'` or the web pack identifiers messing things up.

Comment: I added an example if it doesn't work on your machine its a discussion for another question.

Comment: Your example works, I edited my question with a CodeSandbox on what I am trying to do and how its different.

Comment: I edited my answer, I suggest reading the docs of how implementing a styling component, and read how to override CSS classes in general